# Create a "spiral fracture" in a metacarpal stl file I have for printing

Tags: 3d-printing

I have a few 3d printers and I have access to a digital model of a metacarpal bone that I got from ct scan.  The metacarpal was brought into blender as an .stl and looks like this:

[image]

I'll be printing various versions of this bone with simulated fractures for med students to practice fixing and so far these fractures have been produced either manually in real life by breaking them or by simply using the bisect tool in blender to chop it.  I want to get a little fancier and try to duplicate something like this:
[image]

I've attempted adding a mesh, squishing it into a long strip and then using the deform modifier to twist it, at which point I boolean difference them, but it doesn't seem to be quite right.  Do I keep tinkering with that process or does anyone have better ideas?  What would be simplest and best way to do this?  Keeping in mind it'll have to stay manifold for 3d printing.

Comment: Are there some medical papers provide the **breaking bone formula** for it? You might want to reproduce that formula and use that *plane* for your cutting process. Since you are going to use it as medical teaching material, need to be a little bit precisely job.

Comment: And the *boolean modifier* is not reliable in complicated mesh and overlapping mesh. You might want to scale down the **Overlapping** threshold (maybe `1-e10`) in bool-mod for more precise result.